# Element-wise matrix-vector product with NumPy

Tags: numpy

I have an MxN RGB image, represented as a `(M, N, 3)` array `A`. And I have another `(3, 3)` matrix `B`. I want to left-multiply each pixel (a 3-vector) in `A` by `B` to obtain a `(M, N, 3)` output matrix `C`, so that `C[i][j] = B @ A[i][j]`. How can I do this without looping through the pixels in `A`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this

```
C = (B @ A[...,None]).reshape(A.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use `einsum` for this type of operation:

```
import numpy as np

shape = 10, 20, 3
A = np.random.random(np.product(shape)).reshape(shape)
B = np.random.random(9).reshape((3, 3))

print(np.einsum("ijk,lk", A, B).shape)
```

See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite:

```
C[i][j] = B @ A[i][j]
```

as:

```
C[i,j,:] = B[:,:] @ A[i,j,:]
```

actually I don't think that's right, because `@` pairs the last of the first, with the 2nd to the last of the second.  `A` needs an extra 'dummy' dimension.

Actually its easier to express as:

```
np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl',A,B)
np.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl',A,B.T)
```

so

```
A @ B.T
(B @ A[:,:,:,None]).squeeze()
```

with numbers:

```
In [33]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(2,4,3)
In [34]: B = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [35]: np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl',A,B)
Out[35]: 
array([[[  5,  14,  23],
        [ 14,  50,  86],
        [ 23,  86, 149],
        [ 32, 122, 212]],

       [[ 41, 158, 275],
        [ 50, 194, 338],
        [ 59, 230, 401],
        [ 68, 266, 464]]])
In [36]: A@B.T
Out[36]: 
array([[[  5,  14,  23],
        [ 14,  50,  86],
        [ 23,  86, 149],
        [ 32, 122, 212]],

       [[ 41, 158, 275],
        [ 50, 194, 338],
        [ 59, 230, 401],
        [ 68, 266, 464]]])
In [37]: (B@A[...,None]).squeeze()
Out[37]: 
array([[[  5,  14,  23],
        [ 14,  50,  86],
        [ 23,  86, 149],
        [ 32, 122, 212]],

       [[ 41, 158, 275],
        [ 50, 194, 338],
        [ 59, 230, 401],
        [ 68, 266, 464]]])
```